# Язык C, что говорит Стандарт о размере байта

Tags: c, char

Подскажите, как **Стандарты** регламентируют размер байта?

Я где-то слышал, что в **C** принято соглашение, согласно которому байт может быть только 8-ми битным. Но не могу найти источник.

Многие привыкли оперировать с байтами, используя **char** и **CHAR_BIT**, но ведь **char** бывает не только 8-ми битным.

**CHAR_BIT** тоже вводит в заблуждение, ведь эта макро-константа, вроде бы, не имеет никакого отношения к размеру байта, она относится к битности типа **char**.

Часто возникает необходимость *навигации* по памяти/объектам через **void***, именно побайтово. Кто-то использует для этого приведение к **char***, но это, очевидно, неправильно. Я, например, использую приведение к **uint8_t***, но это, наверняка, тоже неправильно.

Comment: Хороший "недовопрос" про **`uint8_t`**. Сами элементы, конечно, будут хранить 8-bit целые числа, независимо от величины **`CHAR_BIT`**. А адресоваться будут, как  **`char`** (т.е. минимально адресуемый объект). Поэтому, если под байтом, вы понимаете именно 8 бит, то такая адресация не всегда напрямую возможна.

Comment: Почему "недовопрос"?

Comment: Потому что эта часть текста (про `uint8_t`), на мой взгляд, не акцентирована как вопрос. Кстати, напишите в тексте вопроса, *что именно вы считаете байтом*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я нигде не видел соглашения о 8 битах на байт в си. Но откроем стандарт [с11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) - это конечно не сам стандарт, но документ, который очень близок к нему.

пункт 6.2.6 Representations of types дает следующее

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of n × CHAR_BIT bits, where n is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into an object of type unsigned char [n] (e.g., by memcpy);

здесь немного неявно говорится что `n × CHAR_BIT bits` == n байт. То есть `CHAR_BIT` bits это один байт.

При этом пунк 3.6 говорит

> **byte**
>   addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment

то есть, байт - достаточно, что бы вместить любой символьный тип. мда...

> NOTE 1 It is possible to express the address of each individual byte of an object uniquely.

байт должен иметь уникальный адрес

> NOTE 2 A byte is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation defined.

а тут самое оно - кол-во бит определяется имплементацией.

Пункт 5.2.4.2 Numerical limits говорит, что CHAR_BIT как минимум 8 или больше.

Что же делать? Добавить в систему сборки проверку CHAR_BIT == 8 и спать спокойно: платформа скорее всего x86/64, использовать `void*` и `char`, 'memcpy'/'memmove' функции можно, все будет работать.

А вот когда условие не сработает, тогда и начинать поднимать панику и просить документацию к компилятору.

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char) говорят, что не восьмибитным может быть на

- Texas Instruments C54x DSPs (OMAP2) (16 бит)
- Digital Equipment Corporation PDP-6/10 (36 бит)
- IBM 701/704/709/7090/7094 (36 бит)
- UNIVAC 1103/1103A/1105/1100/2200 (36 бит)

Comment: а я разве об этом не написал?

Comment: Пардон, протер глаза и увидел.

Comment: дополнение. В стандарте с++ такая же неразбериха, но читая книгу Страуструпа везде натыкаюсь на то, что он постоянно отождествляет байт, char и 8 бит.

Comment: В с++ sizeof(char) возвращает 1. Страуструп утверждает, что если в вашем компиляторе это не так, то выбросьте его. Думаю, что в си также. Но вот итерацию "побайтно" - а тут все очень сложно, а байт то мы не знаем, сколько бит. Вот октет - он точно восемь

Comment: Значит, в терминологии **C**, наименее адресуемая единица - это байт, и размер байта в битах соответствует размеру **char/unsigned char/signed char**? А **CHAR_BIT**, соответственно, говорит нам, сколько бит в байте, то есть - в наименьшем адресуемом объекте, то есть - в **char/unsigned char/signed char**?

Comment: И наиболее безопасный способ осуществлять *прогнозируемую* побайтовую адресацию по объекту на привычных *платформах*, это приведение к **uint8_t***? Если байт 8-ми битный, то проблем не будет, поскольку если байт 8-ми битный, то **uint8_t** на платформе имеется. А если байт содержит > 8 бит, то тип **uint8_t** использовать просто не получится.

Comment: @KoVadim, sizeof(char), по всей видимости, в любом случае вернет 1. Кажется, я разобрался...)